# Is there a way to lock (make it unable to select) one or more elements in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I am using Google Slides to create some product prototype.

However, sometimes I want to lock an element. Just like what we can do in Adobe Photoshop.

Is there any way that I can make this happen in Google Slides?